# Parsing out values from source file and inserting into a template messages

Tags: sed, cygwin, notepad++

If I have a text file with the following messages, how can I strip out the value after "55=" and "48=" for each message, and populate those values into a new template message where the "55=" and "48=" are from each message in the file?

Source file:

```
Recv: 8=FIX.4.2|9=00258|35=d|49=XXXX|56=XXXX|34=4|52=20151026-16:04:21.972|320=1|322=1:2|323=4|393=43389|15=USD|55=H8X|167=FUT|200=201603|541=20160301|205=1|48=17888384001387914931|207=CME|100=XCME|16552=1|16554=20|454=3|455=HW|456=99|455=H8XH6|456=98|455=H8X Mar16|456=97|10=223|

Recv: 8=FIX.4.2|9=00249|35=d|49=XXXX|56=XXXX|34=5|52=20151026-16:04:21.972|320=1|322=1:3|323=4|393=43389|15=USD|55=BQS|167=FUT|200=201601|541=20160101|205=1|48=17875701615154475972|207=CME|100=XNYM|16552=1|454=3|455=09|456=99|455=BQSF6|456=98|455=BQS Jan16|456=97|10=065|

Recv: 8=FIX.4.2|9=00264|35=d|49=xxx|56=xxx|34=6|52=20151026-16:04:21.972|320=1|322=1:4|323=4|393=43389|15=USD|55=T1A|167=FUT|200=201512|541=20151201|205=1|48=17665452254677820169|207=CME|100=XCBT|16552=0.001|16554=2000|454=3|455=06|456=99|455=T1AZ5|456=98|455=T1A Dec15|456=97|10=141|

Recv: 8=FIX.4.2|9=00268|35=d|49=xxxx|56=xxxx|34=7|52=20151026-16:04:21.972|320=1|322=1:5|323=4|393=43389|15=USD|55=T03|167=FUT|200=201511|541=20151101|205=1|48=17593596635603008360|207=CME|100=XNYM|16460=50|16552=5|16554=0.4|454=3|455=08|456=99|455=T03X5|456=98|455=T03 Nov15|456=97|10=088|
```

Systemically create the same template below with new 55= and 48 values from each message in the source file?

```
8=FIX.4.2|9=195|35=V|49=XXXX|56=XXXX|34=2|52=20151027-21:05:58|262=1|263=1|264=0|265=1|266=Y|267=5|269=0|269=1|269=2|269=4|269=5|146=1|55=HW|48=17888384001387914931|167=FUT|207=CME|10=247|

8=FIX.4.2|9=195|35=V|49=XXXX|56=XXXX|34=2|52=20151027-21:05:58|262=1|263=1|264=0|265=1|266=Y|267=5|269=0|269=1|269=2|269=4|269=5|146=1|55=BQS|48=17875701615154475972|167=FUT|207=CME|10=247|
```

Answer (score 0):

see if this `grep` line helps you:

```
grep -oE '(48|55)=[^|]*' file
```

With your text input, the line above gives:

```
55=H8X
48=17888384001387914931
55=HW
55=H8XH6
55=H8X Mar16
55=BQS
48=17875701615154475972
55=09
55=BQSF6
55=BQS Jan16
55=T1A
48=17665452254677820169
55=06
55=T1AZ5
55=T1A Dec15
55=T03
48=17593596635603008360
55=08
55=T03X5
55=T03 Nov15
55= and 48 values from each message in the source file?
55=HW
48=17888384001387914931
55=BQS
48=17875701615154475972
```